# Use action in component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

Hey I have been reading through redux tutorials online I have followed what I understand from the tutorials, now I want to change the state of different initial states I have set, I have coded the reducer, the action and the store cause that's I read in the tutorial, but I don't know how to change the states in my components based on the actions and reducers I have set, for example, If I want to make `home` false, I have written a `falseHome` action that will do that, but I don't know how to use this in my components,for example I want to change the state of home on navigate, using falseHome, any help will be appreciated, am here to learn, Thanks.

```
**STORE\INDEX.JS**

import { createStore } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "../reducers/index";
const store = createStore(rootReducer);
export default store;

**REDUCERS\INDEX.JS**

import{TRUE_HOME, TRUE_BROWSE,
TRUE_CART, TRUE_MESSAGES,
TRUE_SERVICES, FALSE_BROWSE,
FALSE_CART, FALSE_HOME, FALSE_MESSAGES,
FALSE_SERVICES} from "../constants/action-types";
const initialState = {
messages: false,
home: true,
browse: false,
cart: false,
services: true
};
const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
switch (action.type){
    case TRUE_HOME:
        return{
            ...state,
         home: true
        };
    case FALSE_HOME:
        return{
            ...state,
            home: false
        };
    case TRUE_BROWSE:
        return{
            ...state,
            browse: true
        };
    case FALSE_BROWSE:
        return{
            ...state,
            browse: false
        };
    case TRUE_MESSAGES:
        return{
            ...state,
            messages: true
        };
    case FALSE_MESSAGES:
        return{
            ...state,
            messages: false
        };
    case TRUE_CART:
        return{
            ...state,
            cart: true
        };
    case FALSE_CART:
        return{
            ...state,
            cart: false
        };
    case TRUE_SERVICES:
        return{
            ...state,
            services: true
        };
    case FALSE_SERVICES:
        return{
            ...state,
            services: false
        };
    default:
        return state
}
}
export default rootReducer;

**ACTIONS\INDEX.JS**
import{TRUE_HOME, TRUE_BROWSE,
TRUE_CART, TRUE_MESSAGES,
TRUE_SERVICES, FALSE_BROWSE,
FALSE_CART, FALSE_HOME, FALSE_MESSAGES,
FALSE_SERVICES} from "../constants/action-types";

export const trueHome = home => ({type:
"TRUE_HOME", home: true
});
export const falseHome = home => ({type:
"FALSE_HOME", home: false
});
export const falseBrowse = browse =>({type:
"FALSE_BROWSE", browse: false
});
export const trueBrowse = browse => ({type:
"TRUE_BROWSE", browse: true
});
export const trueMessages = messages => ({type:
"TRUE_MESSAGES", messages: true
});
export const falseMessages = messages => ({type:
"FALSE_MESSAGES", messages: false
});
export const trueCart = cart => ({type:
"TRUE_CART", cart: true
});
export const falseCart = cart => ({type:
"FALSE_CART", cart: false
});
export const trueServices = services => ({type:
"TRUE_SERVICES", services: true
});
export const falseServices = services => ({type:
"FALSE_SERVICES", services: false
});
```

**APP.JS**

```
import store from "./store/index";
import { connect, Provider  } from 'react-redux';
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {        
      timePassed: false,
      On: true,
    };
  }

  render() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({timePassed: true})
    }, 500);
    if (!this.state.timePassed) {
      return <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <StatusBar backgroundColor='transparent' translucent={true} barStyle='light-content'/><Splash/></View>;
    } else {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Provider store={store}>
            <RootStack/>
          </Provider>
        </View>
      );

    }
  }
}
```

**CHILD COMPONENT TO USE ACTION AND SET STATE**

```
//but i don't know how to use the action
 import { connect } from "react-redux";    
 <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={() =>
                    props.navigation.navigate('Shop', {falseHome})}>
```

Comment: You're almost there; I can see you are importing "connect" from react-redux. Head over to the docs on redux and read up what connect does, and how to use it. You will need that before your components can "see" any changes in state.

Comment: Please can you just give me a guide, how can i change the state in any component,a guide will help me to know what I should do or read on

Comment: Any introduction on redux will show you how to do it. SO isn't a teaching resource; it is for when you have a specific programming issue with your code.

Comment: If you want to trigger actions from within your React Components you need to `connect` your Component to Redux state.   Look for `mapDispatchToProps` in the docs.

Comment: @jsplaine Please is my store, action and reducer correct?, am i on the right track

Comment: @AdokiyeIruene I see quite a few issues: 1) your indentation in your code is hard to follow.  2)   You import constants (like `FALSE_HOME`) in ACTIONS\INDEX.JS but you don't use them.  Also, your actions are passing along data that is never used: (ex: `messages: false`) 3) If you want to dispatch redux actions in your Component, you must connect to redux which I still don't see happening here.  Look for `mapDispatchToProps` in the docs. 4) Redux `state` and Component `state` are two entirely different things.  A change in redux state will not change your component state.

Comment: @AdokiyeIruene Regarding Comonents, redux `state`, and Comoponent `state`: `this.setState({})` changes Component state.  A dispatched actions will change Redux state, if your reducer handles the action.  If you connect to Redux `state` via `connect` and `mapStateToProps`, you will see your connected redux state in your Component's `this.props.<mappedReduxState>`.  Your Component will re-render whenever `this.state` or `this.props` is updated (which could happen if your connected redux state/store changes).  If you're still stuck, read through more tutorials and start small.

Comment: Thanks for the help @jsplaine